Search for a specific tuple in a list of tuples sorted by their first element?
Say I have a list of tuples like this, where the int is the "id" for this purpose:
records_by_id = [(10, 'bubble1'), (5, 'bubble2'), (4, 'bubble3'), (0, 'bubble4'), (3, 'bubble5'),]

... and I sort this by the first element of the tuple:
records_by_id.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])

... this gives:
[(0, 'bubble4'), (3, 'bubble5'), (4, 'bubble3'), (5, 'bubble2'), (10, 'bubble1'),]

Now, given the number 4, how do I locate the list index of "(4, 'bubble3')"? Obviously these tuples are now sorted by their first element, so a brute force iteration through the list is not ideal. I'm thinking there must be a way of using bisect ... or something similar. Any ideas?

bisect has a key argument since python 3.10. What python version are you using?

Why are you not using a dict?

@ken 3.10. Thanks, I'll see if I can see how that works for this use case (unless you care to give an answer...).

What if the given number doesn't occur or occurs multiple times?

@nocomment I could, of course. But I'd like to know if there's a non-dict way to do this. Also with this case it is possible to cater for a situation where 2 tuples have the same first element value.

Reuse the sort key for bisecting:
from bisect import bisect_left

records_by_id = [(10, 'bubble1'), (5, 'bubble2'), (4, 'bubble3'), (0, 'bubble4'), (3, 'bubble5'),]

key = lambda x: x[0]
records_by_id.sort(key=key)

index = bisect_left(records_by_id, 4, key=key)

print(index)

Attempt This Online!
If it's possible that the given number doesn't occur, add a check at the end checking whether it actually occurs at the resulting index.

Thanks. This new "sort/bisect on key" thing (since 3.10) really makes for an elegant solution.

@mikerodent Yeah, I think it's the most proper/general way. Although in this particular case I also like John's searching of the tuple (4,).

You're not far from the actual solution. Since you already sorted the list by the first element of the tuple, you can indeed use bisect module to find the index of the tuple given the first element of it.
import bisect

def find_tuple_index(sorted_list, target_id):
    index = bisect.bisect_left(sorted_list, (target_id,))
    if index < len(sorted_list) and sorted_list[index][0] == target_id:
        return index
    return -1  # Not found

# Your sorted list
records_by_id = [(0, 'bubble4'), (3, 'bubble5'), (4, 'bubble3'), (5, 'bubble2'), (10, 'bubble1')]

# Search for the tuple with id 4
result = find_tuple_index(records_by_id, 4)
print(result)  # Output: 2

Let me elaborate a bit on the explanation of the code.

First we use bisect.bisect_left() to find the insertion point for the target ID. This function works because our list is sorted by the first element of each tuple.

Now bisect_left() returns the leftmost place in the list where we can insert the target value while maintaining the sort order.

We then check if the found index is within the list bounds and if the first element of the tuple at that index matches our target ID.

If there's a match, we return the index, otherwise we return -1 to say the item wasn't found.


Btw I've assumed that the IDs in your list are unique. If you might have duplicate IDs you'd need to modify the function to handle that case, maybe by returning a list of all matching indices.
Edit: the complexity of the approach is O(log n) btw

@Olivier Obviously John is talking only about the searching, in the already sorted list, exactly as intended by the question.

I appreciate your passion @Olivier , but let's clear this up. Yes, sorting is O(nlogn). No one's disputing basic algorithms here. But as you might have noticed, the question specifically asked about searching in a sorted list. That's where my O(logn) comment applies. We're not here to rehash Sorting 101, right? ;)
So let's stay cool and focus on helping the community, I'm sure you'll be ok with that

You can indeed use bisect module to find the index of the tuple with the id you've given.
import bisect
# sorting
records_by_id = [(0, 'bubble4'), (3, 'bubble5'), (4, 'bubble3'), (5, 'bubble2'), (10, 'bubble1')]

# id you wanna find
target_id = 4

# create a list of the first ids from the tuples
ids = [x[0] for x in records_by_id]

# use bisect_left to find the index where the target_id would be inserted to maintain sorted order and check if the id at that index is the target_id
index = bisect.bisect_left(ids, target_id)
if index < len(records_by_id) and records_by_id[index][0] == target_id:
    print(f"Found at index: {index}")
else:
    print("Not found")


import bisect

records_by_id = [(0, 'bubble4'), (3, 'bubble5'), (4, 'bubble3'), (5, 'bubble2'), (10, 'bubble1')]

def find_tuple_index(records, target_id):
    # Create a list of just the IDs for binary search
    ids = [record[0] for record in records]
    
    # Use bisect to find the insertion point
    index = bisect.bisect_left(ids, target_id)
    
    # Check if the index is valid and the ID matches
    if index != len(records) and records[index][0] == target_id:
        return index
    return -1  # Not found

# Example usage
target_id = 4
result_index = find_tuple_index(records_by_id, target_id)
print(f"Tuple with ID {target_id} found at index: {result_index}")

Given a target ID (For example 4), I need to efficiently find the index of the corresponding tuple in this list. In this case,I want to find the index of

(4,'bubble3')

A Linear search is not ideal as the list is already sorted. And we are using bisect.
My Answer imports bisect and uses

bisect.bisect.left()

to find isertion point of the target ID.
Checks if the found index is valid and if the ID matches the target, returns the index is found, or -1 if not.
